# Import csv and update records in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file in php and update existing records in mysql database but my code just won't work, it does not have any errors but it won't update my database. Here's is the code.

```
<?php  

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("department",$connect); //select the table  

if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && ($_FILES['csv']['size']) > 0) {

get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO students (studno, lastname, firstname, mi,    
        sy, sem, course, deptname) VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                '".addslashes($data[7])."',
            ) 
        "); 
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

header('Location: admin/uploadinfo.php?success=1'); die; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
function getdata($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'test.csv';

$csv = getdata($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Project
            [1] => Date
            [2] => User
            [3] => Activity
            [4] => Issue
            [5] => Comment
            [6] => Hours
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => 04/30/2015
            [2] => test
            [3] => test
            [4] => test
            [5] => 
            [6] => 6.00
        ));
```